# Form not displaying PHP Log showing Undefined index

Tags: php, oop, class, forms

I am getting the following errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  Username class.form.php on line 43
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  Password class.form.php on line 54
```

[index.php code](http://pastebin.com/HAHnJJM1)

[class.form.php code](http://pastebin.com/nMr2Ue2f)

The form is showing in the source code but not the "view"

print_r is showing `Form Object ( [sHTML:Form:private] =>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the last error, change:

`<?php echo $sLoginMessage ?>`

to

`<?php echo (isset($sLoginMessage)?$sLoginMessage:null); ?>`

With your other error, you're trying to access an array index that does not exist. `$this->aStickyData[$sName]` and the other aStickyData error is because these array indexes are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The first two errors are referring to your attempts to access `Form::$aStickyData['Username']` and `Form::$aStickyData['Password']` respectively.

This data is only set on form submission. You should set default data for the initial page load.

The last error is because you're defining `$sLoginMessage` inside the form submission and validation conditions. You should define it earlier.